# How to wrap a variable with a method in bytecode ASM JAVA

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I am trying to encrypt a variable in a parameter in a method call using ASM while traversing the instructions in a method node.

For now I have tried making the string to be encrypted in the previous line of the method call(in actual java code).

ie. if the line is Logger("This is a log",a)

What my algorithm does is it makes, a = Project.Util.encode(a);  in the previous line of the logger. Sample code is given below.

```
if(abstractNode instanceof VarInsnNode) {
    VarInsnNode varnode = (VarInsnNode) abstractNode;
        insnList.add(new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "com/sample/Project", "Util", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
        insnList.add(new VarInsnNode(ALOAD,varnode.var));
        insnList.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"));
       insnList.add(new VarInsnNode(ASTORE,varnode.var));
     }
```

I calculate the parameters from the method call description.Whenever I find a variable, I make a encoding by mutating its value And at the end of the method call byte structure (By traversing in upward direction) I paste those instructions before them.

But I want to remove its usage like that. Instead I want to make like this.

Logger("This is a log",encode(a));

Consider I hit the variable a as a abstract node.
I try to add instruction before and after this particular variable like.

```
 methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(abstractNode, new FieldInsnNode(GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;"));
 methodNode.instructions.insertBefore(abstractNode.getNext(),new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "encode", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;"));
```

It turns to be a failure says No Sufficient space in stack.

Please help me in this view.

Comment: Have you tried calling `visitMax`?

Comment: No I haven't. Plus I don't use any type of visits in my Code.
I iterate thru all the method node in the class and iterate through all the instructions.

Comment: I create abstract node out of the instruction and do the process

Comment: I am not writing a new class file. I read the class file then I try to find a specific methodCall and read the count of params and and check for variable by checking the instance of the abstractinsnnode.

Comment: Could you please post the exact error messages you are getting then?